# Using Angularjs, how to avoid that the cursor moves at the end of an input when both ng-model and value={{}} are set

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angularjs, HAML and Rails.

Whenever I set both ng-model and value in an element, the cursor moves at the end each time I type anything.

This is a sample input:

```
%textarea{:name=>"task", :value=>"{{s.description}}", :placeholder=>"Doing this...", "ng-model"=>"s.description"}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple. Just remove the attribute ":value" from the input and leave "ng-model".

```
%textarea{:name=>"task", :placeholder=>"Doing this...", "ng-model"=>"s.description"}
```

With that the input element will work as expected.